# Detecting projective dimension of finitely generated modules over Noetherian semi-perfect rings via vanishing of Ext on simple modules

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, homological-algebra, projective-module, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a Noetherian semi-perfect
ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated left $R$-module. Let $n \geq 0$ be an integer. If $\text{Ext}^{n+1}_R(M,S)=0$ for every simple left $R$-module $S$, then is it true that $M$ has projective dimension at most $n$? Can the assumption semi-perfect be weakened to semi-local (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-local_ring) ?

If this is well-known, I would be happy with a reference that also discusses the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for semi-local rings.

Suppose $R$ is semi-local, so $R/\operatorname{rad}R$ is semisimple. Suppose that $M$ is finitely generated with $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,S)=0$ for every simple $R$-module $S$.

Take a projective resolution
$$0\to X\to P_n\to\cdots\to P_1\to P_0\to M\to0$$
of $M$ by finitely generated projective modules, truncated after the $P_n$ term, so $M$ is the kernel of the differential $P_n\to P_{n-1}$.

Since $X$ is finitely generated and $R$ is semilocal, $X/\operatorname{rad}X$ is a direct sum of finitely many simple modules, and so $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,X/\operatorname{rad}X)=0$.

Therefore the quotient map $X\to X/\operatorname{rad}X$ factors as $X\to P_n\xrightarrow{\alpha}X/\operatorname{rad}X$ for some $\alpha$. Since $P_n$ is projective, $\alpha$ lifts to a map $\tilde{\alpha}:P_n\to X$, and the composition $X\to P_n\to X$ must be surjective, since $\operatorname{rad}X$ is a superfluous submodule of $X$. But a surjective endomorphism $f$ of a Noetherian module $X$ is invertible, as otherwise $\ker(f)\subset\ker(f^2)\subset\ker(f^3)\subset\cdots$ would be an ascending chain of submodules.

So $X\to P_n\to X$ is an isomorphism, and so the inclusion $X\to P_n$ is the inclusion of a direct summand, and so if $Q_n$ is a complement of $X$ in $P_n$ then
$$0\to Q_n\to P_{n-1}\to\cdots\to P_1\to P_0\to M\to0$$
is a projective resolution of $X$, and so $X$ has projective dimension at most $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does the surjection of the composition $X\to P_n \to X$ imply that the injective map $X\to P_n$ splits? I understand the rest of the argument but not this point ...

Comment: Since $X$ is finitely generated, and hence Noetherian, a surjective map $f:X\to X$ must be an isomorphism (or else the submodules $\ker(f^n)$ would be a strictly increasing sequence of submodules).

Comment: @Alex I've edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you. I am quite new to general associative rings, so it takes me a while to see what results from commutative rings hold for any associative rings as well ...

Comment: Do you think the answer would be affirmative if we just had $\text{Ext}^{n+1}_R(M, R/J(R))=0$? I know $R/J(R)$ is a finite direct sum of simple modules, but I cannot decide if all simplest appear in the summand or not (they do in the Commutative case). If I try to follow your argument, with your notation, I just need a superfluous submodule $X''$ of $X$ with the required Ext vanishing. Does $X''=rad(X)$ or $J(R)X$ work?

Comment: @Alex All simples appear in $R/J(R)$ just as in the commutative case.  If $S$ is a simple left module, and $0\neq s\in S$ then $r\mapsto rs$ is a nonzero (and therefore surjective, since $S$ is simple) homomorphism $R\to S$. So every simple module is a quotient of $R$, and hence of $R/J(R)$.

Comment: I was wondering if you would also be able to shed some light on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716042/when-does-a-finitely-generated-module-over-a-noetherian-semi-local-ring-surject  ? Thank you